# System of first order differential equations problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations which I need to solve and obtain $y(x)$ and $z(x)$. I tried elimination method and got to a point but I don't know what to do after here. Any help would be appreciated
Question:
$$y'(x)=\frac{x+y}{z}$$
$$z'(x)=\frac{x-y}{y}$$

[My solution until the point I got stuck.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29uTO.png)
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'(x)=\dfrac{x+y}{z} \\z'(x)=\dfrac{x-y}{y}$$
$$y'(x)z={x+y} \\z'(x)y={x-y}$$
Sum both differential equations:
$$y'z+z'y=2x$$
$$(yz)'=2x$$
$$\implies yz =x^2+C$$
The second DE is:
$$z'(x)y={x-y}$$
$$z'=\dfrac x y-1$$
$$z'=\dfrac {zx}{x^2+C} -1$$
That you can solve.

---

**Edit1**
$$z'=\dfrac {\color {red}{z}x}{x^2+C} -1$$
You can't integrate both sides the way you did because there is the $z$ function on RHS:
$$z'-\dfrac {zx}{x^2+C}= -1$$
$$\sqrt {x^2+C}z'-\dfrac {zx}{\sqrt {x^2+C}}= -\sqrt {x^2+C}$$
$$\left ( \dfrac  z {\sqrt {x^2+C}}\right)'=-\dfrac 1 {\sqrt {x^2+C}}$$
Now you can integrate both sides.
$$ \dfrac  z {\sqrt {x^2+C}}=-\int \dfrac {dx} {\sqrt {x^2+C}}+C_2$$
$$ z(x) ={\sqrt {x^2+C}}\left (C_2-\arctan \dfrac {x} {\sqrt {x^2+C}} \right)$$

Comment: I tried integrating both sides and obtained (zln(x^2+c1))/(2)-x+c2. But I got the feedback that it's wrong solution. Could you give me a tip where I might be doing something wrong?

Comment: You cant integrate both sides that way there is a z on RHS. It"s a first order differential equation. Find an integrating factor. @BoraKutlu

Comment: I added some lines I hope it's more clear now @BoraKutlu